# How to decrypt a string that I know its pattern in Python?

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary

I'm working on an encrypted string that is made up of 5 integers, and I figured out its pattern, I tried to write a python `OrderedDict` like this:

```
od = OrderedDict([('0', '9'), ('1', '2'), ('2', '0'), ('3', '7'), ('4', '1'), 
                  ('5', '3'), ('6', '8'), ('7', '6'), ('8', '5'), ('9', '4')])
```

So I wrote some codes to decrypt the string.
The "encrypted" string is an example.

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for k, v in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(k, v)
    return text


encrypted = '14012'
decrypted = replace_all(encrypted, od)
```

I just can't get the correct answer, the string `14012` should be decrypted to `21920`,but I just get `01400`.

What should I do with my codes to get the correct string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@blhsing has it right, think about what happens to text each loop:

```html
>>> decrypted = replace_all(encrypted, od)
14912
24922
04900
01900
01400
```

You will want to translate item by item

I like `''.join([od[i] for i in encrypted])`

Answer (score 3):

You iterate over the dict items one by one, so `'1'` gets translated to `'2'`, and then `'2'` gets translated to `'0'`, which is why the result starts with `'0'` instead of `'2'`, for example.

You can use the [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) method instead:

```
table = ''.join(od.get(chr(i), chr(i)) for i in range(256))
print(encrypted.translate(table))
```

This outputs:

```
21920
```

There's no need to use `OrderedDict` in this case, by the way, since order does not matter in building the translation table.

Comment: I’ve changed the wrong string given in my question, thanks for your answer!

Comment: If there is not need to use `OrderedDict`，can I replace od with a normal dictionary like 

     od={'0':'9','1':'2' ...}

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean.